# static html in windows

Tags: html, windows, localhost

I have a static html website in a folder on Windows XP. If I open the file directly from its location, the page loads in a browser, but none of the relative links work. They all want to be relative to localhost, not the directory they're in.

I can drop the project in IIS and it works fine, but I'd like to be able to skip that step and just browse the project without needing a server.

But my question is simply this: is there something I can do so I can view the website locally, through a browser, without a server?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried: Save Page As (Webpage, complete) when viewing it on a server?

Comment: The whole story is that I'm building the site in rails, then using wget to make a pure html version of the site. So, in my folder is a complete web app, with html files, stylesheets, javascripts, and images. It's all there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<base>` Defines the base URL or target for all relative links.
It goes in the `<head>` tag.

It can also be useful for developers who build websites in one location (dev) that will ultimately be placed in another location (prod).

```
<base href="http://myfolder/test/">
```

There is some discussion -- and some more examples for you -- in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/is-it-recommended-to-use-the-base-html-tag).